# Resizing jScrollPane when dropdowns are expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I'm trying to add the jScrollPane custom bar  to this menu which has dropdown links within it. I need the scroll bar to resize upon click and dynamic content being added to the menu. any ideas of how to do this.

Example of the issue
http://jsfiddle.net/1eddy87/7zXPB/5/

I tried to append content however had no success. example below

```
$(function()
{
    // Initialise the scrollpanes
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();

    // Add some content to #pane2
    var pane2api = $('#pane2').data('jsp');
    var originalContent = pane2api.getContentPane().html();
    pane2api.getContentPane().html(originalContent + originalContent + originalContent);

    // Reinitialise the #pane2 scrollpane
    pane2api.reinitialise();
});
```

Here are some working examples:

1. http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/less_basic.html
2. " /dynamic_content.html  "

Comment: Fair enough, how about posting what you've tried so far (and maybe a JSFiddle to play with)?

Comment: Update: hope this give you a better idea. http://jsfiddle.net/1eddy87/7zXPB/5/